# $X-P$ is countable, if $P$ if the set of condensation points and $X$ is a separable metric space.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

I am studying basic Topology on my own, and I would like to have a check on my proof of the statement below.

(Note: there is a similar exercise on Baby Rudin, Ex. 27, Ch. 2, applied to $\mathbb R^k$, but my line of reasoning is different.)

**Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space, and $P$ be the set of condensation points of $X$. Show that $X-P$ is countable.**

*Proof.* I will make use of Lindelöf covering theorem, and show that if $X-P$ were uncountable then there would be an open covering $\mathcal N$ of $X-P$ with no countable subcovering, thus contradicting the separability of $X$.

Suppose then $X-P$ is uncountable. Take an element $s \in X-P$ and a neighborhood $N(x)$ of $x$ that contains only countably many points of $X$ (this is possible since $s \not \in P$). Add $N(x)$ to the collection of open sets $\mathcal N$. This "leaves out" uncountably many points of $X-P$. So we can pick another one and add to $\mathcal N$ a neighborood of such point, containing only a finite subset of $X$.

By repeating this procedure we create the open cover $\mathcal N$ which is uncountable (the countable union of countable sets is in fact countable), and such that no countable subcollection of $\mathcal N$ covers $X-P$. This (by Lindelöf theorem) contradicts separability of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of $\mathcal{N}$ can be tightened up considerably, but the argument is basically correct.

Your argument is a very informal and slightly hand-wavy version of a proof using transfinite recursion to construct, one set at a time, an open cover of $X\setminus P$ with no countable subcover. This is intuitively satisfying and can be made rigorous, but to do so requires some basic knowledge of infinite ordinal numbers or at least some experience working with uncountable well-ordered sets.

It’s actually easier, if perhaps less intuitive, to construct an open cover all at once and use it to show directly that $X\setminus P$ must be countable.

> **Proof:** By definition each $x\in X\setminus P$ has a countable open nbhd $N(x)$. Let $\mathcal{N}=\{N(x):x\in X\setminus P\}$; $\mathcal{N}$ is an open cover of $X\setminus P$, so it has a countable subcover $\mathscr{C}$. Then $X\setminus P\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{C}$, so $|X\setminus P|\le\left|\bigcup\mathscr{C}\right|$. And $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$ is the union of countably many countable sets, so it is countable, and $X\setminus P$ is therefore countable as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and your proof!

Comment: @dfnu: You’re welcome!